# PHP preg_replace more spaces only when after specific substring

Tags: php, preg-replace

I would like to ensure a sufficient readability of a multiline string which contains a code snippet. The goal is to replace normal whitespaces with non breaking spaces so the code snippet is readable in a web browser.

I already replaced all cr+lf with nl2br.
But I need to replace all whitespaces that come just after HTML break tag with  
No other whitespaces should be touched.

I tried:

```
$text = nl2br($text);
$text = preg_replace('/(<br \/>)+(\s+)/', '$1&nbsp;', $text);
```

but that only replaced one whitespace after HTML break tag.

I want the text (which is result of nl2br):

```
some text<br />  some other text
```

become:

```
some text<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;some other text
```

How to do that using preg_replace correctly?

Comment: Could you add some code so we can see what you already tried and continue from that point?

Comment: `so the code snippet is readable in a web browser` - just wrap snippet in `<code>` or `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Now it should be clear, sorry for pressing the Post Question foo early.

Comment: @ankhzet: This I can't do, the DB is already filled with many hundreds of such texts and I need to make them just more readable now

Comment: `This I can't do` - can't change htm markup or tried `pre` tag and it changed nothing?

Comment: It would be too much work to add the code formatting to all the texts now. The texts contain ANY combinations of normal text and code snippets. You can't wrap all the text with code or pre tag.

Comment: You can convert sole code snippets, but can't wrap them? Erm, how?!

Comment: The texts are: `normal text<br />other normal text<br />  some code snippet<br />just another normal text<br />  some other code snippet` etc. Can't wrap entire text because normal text is combined with code snippets in arbitrary way. It is clear that the code snippets will have the same font etc. but the initial spaces will not be stripped by web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way is:

```
    $c_text = str_replace("\r", '', $c_text);
    $c_text = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $c_text);
    $c_text = preg_replace_callback('#<br \/>(\s+)#', function ($match) {
      return '<br />' . str_pad("", strlen($match[1]) * 6, "&nbsp;");
    }, $c_text);
```

This makes the texts appear as I wanted.
Above solution with `pre` tag would not work because the code snippets may start at newline even without leading whitespace.

Also keep in mind that nl2br does not replace cr+lf so str_replace is needed as seen in this and previous answer.

You may check the final results at http://tkweb.eu/en/delphicomp/kcontrols.html, the texts are the comments below the article. This web site was made a long time ago and now I just needed a quick improvement of comment readability wo changing them. Because I have no time to make a better system now.

Comment: doesn't it better to just set `white-space` css property of the comment container to `pre-wrap`? It will force browser to preserve whitespace, without any text-conversions on each run...

Comment: btw, isn't it just the same, as i suggested in first part of my answer?

Comment: @ankzet: It is almost the same as your proposals. I just tested them and combined them together. Is exactly the code what I use now. I did not know about pre-wrap css style, thank you for hint. I'll keep now this solution but for future it is good to know about the css option.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('#<br\s*/?>(\s+)#', function ($match) {
    $pad = '';
    $l = strlen($match[1]);
    while ($l-- > 0)
        $pad .= '&nbsp';
    return '<br />' . $pad;
}, $text);`
```

And with just wrapping in `<pre>` tag:

```
$text = "normal text\nother normal text\n some code snippet\n some code snippet\njust another normal text\njust another normal text\n some other code snippet";

$text2 = str_replace("\r", '', $text);

$text2 = preg_replace('#((\n\s+[^\n$]+)+)(\n|$)#', '<pre>[\1]</pre>', $text2);
$text2 = str_replace("\n", '<br />', $text2);

echo "<div>$text2</div>";
```

Result:

```
<div>normal text<br />other normal text<pre>[<br /> some code snippet<br /> some code snippet]</pre>just another normal text<br />just another normal text<pre>[<br /> some other code snippet]</pre></div>
```

...shown as:

```
normal text
other normal text
[
 some code snippet
 some code snippet]
just another normal text
just another normal text
[
 some other code snippet]
```

*Notice square brackets around "code snippets".*

Comment: This is not possible. This will replace ALL whitespaces. I need only those after a HTML break tag and following first non-whitespace char.

Comment: Ok, I'll test tomorrow. I knew it would work somehow with this but I wanted to know if it worked with just preg_replace.

Comment: AFAIK, preg_replace can execute php code in patterns (like, `preg_replace('#(patt?ern+)#e', '"patte" .str_pad('$1', 10) . "rn"')`), but that is really slow and, in fact, is obsolete and `preg_replace_callback` suggested to use instead...

Comment: Alright, thank you much. Will test what you proposed.

Comment: Could simplify to `return str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $match[1]);` then you just replace all spaces with their entity.

Comment: @chris85, yeah, more handy, but more time-consuming. Another option is to use `return "<br />" . str_pad("", strlen($match[1]) * 6, "&nbsp;");`